# How to create a Facebook ad post (promotable_posts) using koala gem?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I was trying to create a FB ads post through koala gem:

```
page_graph.put_connections(page_id,"promotable_posts",params)
```

where params

```
params = {
                         "message" => 'my_message',
                         "name" => "my_name",
                         "link" => "www.link.com",
                         "caption" => "my_caption",
                         "description" => "This is a longer description",
                         "picture" => "https://pic.com/1234"
                      }
```

The error am getting is

`Koala::Facebook::ClientError: type: GraphMethodException, code: 100, error_subcode: 33, message: Unsupported post request. Object with ID '<page_id>' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api, x-fb-trace-id:XXXX [HTTP 400]`

I have given all the permissions for creating ads `posts(ads_management,ads_read)` Also, I am able to get the ads_posts for a page:

```
page_graph.get_connections(page_id,"promotable_posts" ) but am not able to create one.
```

How can I debug this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.3#pages: _“The Page promotable_posts edge is deprecated.”_

Comment: oh my bad :(, I've checked the API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/page/ads_posts and it seems like we cannot create ads_posts using it. BTW Thanks for the help!